# drupal switch from 2 different menu

Tags: drupal, menu, amp-html

I have a drupal website with amp module.
How i can make to switch 2 different menu, one for AMP version and one for normal version?

I'm trying to put this expression: /*?amp but dosent work

Comment: Are you also using the AMP theme? You can specify active blocks per theme. If both normal and AMP versions of your nodes use the same theme, you would need to change the block's content via custom module using the block hooks.

Comment: make a condtion on amp param in preprocess to override initial menu . or you can develop entire theme for amp and drive it on amp param

Answer (score 0):

**/*?amp** just give you the view of the AMP page of the current node if it exists.

I would suggest you to use [**AMP module**](https://www.drupal.org/project/amp). Which will also add required [**library**](https://github.com/Lullabot/amp-library) and [**theme**](https://www.drupal.org/project/amptheme) needed for it.
Now you can create a sub theme for AMP having [**AMP Theme**](https://www.drupal.org/project/amptheme) as a base theme of it.
now just you have to create a Specific AMP menu and placed it to the region defined under your custom theme and visiting on AMP page you will able to see your AMP specific menu.

Please let me know if you need more information related to it.

Comment: I know. I already install AMP module , library and theme. My question was different: i need to create all menu for AMP? Or is there something that switch automatically to AMP menu adding ?amp on each link?

Comment: can you please confirm how are you going to make AMP specific menu?. As per my understanding you want to make different amp menu from the existing menu on normal page. In this case my answer will be NO. you have to make new AMP menu and place it to defined region of the amp theme and it will work as expected.